# @CDK/python How to get ARN of a resources created by CDK

Tags: python, aws-cdk, amazon-elb

I'm trying to get a load balancer ARN that is created by CDK

Load balancer is created using

```
        lb = lbv2.CfnLoadBalancer(self, "LB",
                                    name = config.loadbalancer.name,
                                    scheme= "internet-facing",
                                    security_groups=[core.Fn.ref(config.loadbalancer.sgname)],
                                    subnets = [public_subnets[0],public_subnets[1]],
                                    type = config.loadbalancer.type
                                    )
```

Trying to retrieve the ARN for load balancer and listener group

```
        lb_listeners= lbv2.CfnListener(self, "LBlisteners",
                                       default_actions = [{"Type":"forward","TargetGroupArn":target_groups.listenerArn, "Order" : 1}],
                                       load_balancer_arn = core.Fn.ref("Lb"))
```

Both method is failing `target_groups.listenerArn` and referrig it back using `core.Fn.ref("Lb")`

Comment: Error 
`AttributeError: 'CfnTargetGroup' object has no attribute 'listenerArn`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the Cfn Functions generally do not have all the same hooks as fully fleshed out cdk constructs. Cfn (meaning CloudFormation) are escape hatches that are used to put things in CDK that haven't been developed for CDK yet, and are pretty much just straight pushes. That is a caveat to say that you cannot expect any construct you have to use cfn with to work with every other construct - the hooks simply aren't there.

First off, as it appears you are using Python, its usually {construct}_arn like table_arn or function_arn. (snake case)

Second, if you have a decent linter and intelli-sense, it should pop a list of potential attributes when you put the dot down. You should be able to do a partial match and arn will be one.

Finally, the cdk documentation says it pretty clearly: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2/CfnListener.html#aws_cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.CfnListener.attr_listener_arn

so in effect, you probably will need to use:

```
lb_listeners= lbv2.CfnListener(self, "LBlisteners",
                                   default_actions = [{"Type":"forward","TargetGroupArn":target_groups.listenerArn, "Order" : 1}],
                                   load_balancer_arn = lb.attr_listener_arn)
```

(core.Fn.ref() is another escape hatch function that should generally only be used when getting really into the nitty gritty of unfinished constructs)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. it worked, and i have learned it in a hard way using L1 construct like `cfn` is not that useful for passing things to others.

Comment: Glad it worked. Try to stay away from then L1 constructs if you can, the fully fleshed out ones have great hooks that make it easier. If the answe was helpful, please consider marking it as such

Comment: why do you pass the listener arn to load_balancer_arn and not the arn of the load balancer?

Comment: @RonyTesler it's been quite some time since I've worked with cdk, but my best guess at remembering is that the above code is instantiating the Listener, and it needs to be told what load balancer to attach the listener too. I would definitely look to see if Listeners and Load balancers have T2 functionality now (no longer using the cfn functions) because they will br much better to use.

Comment: @RonyTesler or I screwed up the code. That's always a possibility too xD